# Avoiding the embedded tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

I am using eclipse as my development IDE. I created a Server Runtime Environment using tomcat and I am able to run the project on the server which basically runs on the tomcat local to eclipse.

I would really love to directly run this project on the tomcat server which is present in my C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/tomcat/ directory.

Is there a way where I can force eclipse to run the projects on the tomcat I want instead of running it on the local eclipse copy of the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First publish your server by right clicking it and publish. Then double click the server and change the Server Locations as seen in the image attached. [image: Server Locations]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a server runtime in eclipse which points to "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/tomcat/" using 
NEW-->SERVER-->click on configure runtime environments
this will use the server which is located your folder.
I hope i am able to clarify.